# Execute methods which don't accept arguments

Tags: go, reflection

Given an arbitrary instance of a struct, I'd like to be able to execute all of its public methods which don't accept arguments.

For example in the code below, I'd like to be able to execute X{}.Foo() and X{}.Bar() without knowing that they exist.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type X struct {
    Y string
}

func (x X) Foo() string {
    return x.Y
}

func (x X) Bar() {
}

func (x X) Baz(q string) {
}

func main() {
    fooType := reflect.TypeOf(X{})
    for i := 0; i < fooType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := fooType.Method(i)
        fmt.Println(method.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change [`reflect.TypeOf`](https://godoc.org/reflect#TypeOf) to [`reflect.ValueOf`](https://godoc.org/reflect#ValueOf)
2. Check the [type](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type) of the [`Method`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Method) to ensure that is accepts zero parameters
3. Call the method with [`Call`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Call)

```
foo := reflect.ValueOf(X{})
for i := 0; i < foo.NumMethod(); i++ {
    method := foo.Method(i)
    if method.Type().NumIn() == 0 {
        method.Call(nil)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KYAfaFlEjVt